# Binding к свойству Visibility окна

Tags: wpf

Я создал wpf-window как class library. Как мне сделать binding с конвертером к свойству Visibility окна? При выполнении возникает исключение XamlParseException. Стили и словари ресурсов я добавляю в Window.Resources, а не в Application.Resources, поэтому и стиль окна у меня DynamicResource. А с конвертером так не получилось.

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    Style="{DynamicResource MyWindow}" 
    Visibility="{Binding MyModel.IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisConverter}}">
<Window.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="MyDictionary.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>            
  </ResourceDictionary>
  <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
...
```

Comment: Конкретно в моем случае - подошел. Надо только добавить Mode="TwoWay".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в `StaticResource`: ресурс должен быть определён до точки использования.

Попробуйте так:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    Style="{DynamicResource MyWindow}">
<Window.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="MyDictionary.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>            
  </ResourceDictionary>
  <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Visibility>
  <Binding Path="MyModel.IsVisible" Converter="{StaticResource boolToVisConverter}"/>
</Window.Visibility>
<Window.DataContext>
  ...
```